# How to increase my bodyweight?

Tags: nutrition, diet, weight

I am 19 years old, am 6 feet and 1 inch (1.85 meters) tall, and I weigh 130 pounds (59 kilograms). How can I increase my body weight? Are there any tablets that will do the job? Possibly the ones bodybuilders take to gain weight?

Comment: If you are not intolerant. Adding a Gallon of (Full Fat/Whole) Milk a Day (GOMAD) to your diet is a great way to put in a lot of calories that aren't carbohydrates.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can answer this question as I'm in similar situation.
You can definitely gain weight by following these steps:

1. **Consult a doctor** and get yourself checked so as to make sure that you don't have any medical problem or any food allergy.
2. Because you need to gain weight, you will have to **start eating more** than you do now. So, increase your number of meals from 3 to 4 and from 4 to 5. First, eat less in each diet but increase diet frequency. A time will come when you will start eating after every two hours of so.
3. **Exercise**. It will take regular practise but you can start with these [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9dfU99VvuQ)
4. And you need to make sure that you eat healthy afterwards you start gaining weight. It will confirm that the weight you gain is not in fat. So exercises and proper diet.
5. Hoping that you follow these steps and do not give up.

sources: http://www.hsph.harvard.edu/nutritionsource/healthy-weight/

Comment: Just a point - If you eat in a large excess of your daily caloric needs, you will gain fat, whether or not you are eating healthy.

Comment: Yes, I agree but as his BMI is low, so putting on a pound of fat won't be that much harmful.
And, I am also trying to put on some serious weight :-)